# Integration testing with TomEE embedded and Microprofile fault tolerance

Tags: java, integration-testing, apache-tomee, fault-tolerance, microprofile

I need to test some components in JavaEE environment which are using annotatations from [Microprofile](http://microprofile.io/) project, i.e. @Asynchronous and @Timeout from [fault tolerance part](http://microprofile.io/project/eclipse/microprofile-fault-tolerance) of project. Implementation library for fault tolerance is [Apache safe guard](https://github.com/apache/geronimo-safeguard).
In other to test I'm using Arquillian with TomEE embbedded.

Problem is that during execution of test cases those annotations are ignored, but when application is running on normal TomEE server at least @Timeout is working as expected.

In other to debug little I take one TCK test case from [AsynchronousTest.java](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-fault-tolerance/blob/master/tck/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/fault/tolerance/tck/AsynchronousTest.java) and imported in my project to test:

```
@Test
public void testAsyncIsNotFinished() {
    Future<Connection> future = null;
    try {
        future = client.service();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new AssertionError("testAsync: unexpected InterruptedException calling service");
    }

    Assert.assertFalse(future.isDone());}
```

And this case is failling.